# How To Prevent Request 500 Error in React.js?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, axios, http-post

I'm building a project. Client side is React.js and Server side is MCV(Web Api). Sometimes some of my functions' requests(axios) return 500 error. But This is a momentary error. Because When I call this service again in a while then it works well.  Is there any way to prevent it? Is it a solution if I call this function using try-catch when it goes catch then call it again? Can you give me some advice what way should I go?

Comment: ***This is a momentary error.*** You should examine server side (if you own it) why it throws 500.

Comment: This is a huge project. And In the beginning of project , client side was ext.net and server side was created by WCF. And as you know this is a slow and ol-fashion structure. And I just create client side with React.js. That's why I call server functions as web api(mvc controller). In the ext.net * using (new System.ServiceModel.OperationContextScope((System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel)client.InnerChannel))* this. method was used before call server functions. But I don't know equivalent of this structure in React.js

Comment: If you don't post a [mre] to show the issue you face, it's impossible to provide a solution. Please edit and add a [mre] which highlights your issue.